# Combine two conditions in one statement syntax

Tags: customization, filters

I have two queries that I would like to combine because it becomes a lot of code and I think that's not necessary but I make a mistake with the syntax

I want to combine

```
} elseif (is_category( 'latest-news' )) {
```

With

```
} elseif ( is_single() && in_category('latest-news')) {
```

I tried

```
elseif (is_category( 'latest-news' )) || ( is_single() && in_category('latest-news')) {
```

and

```
elseif (is_category( 'latest-news' )) or ( is_single() && in_category('latest-news')) {
```

but they both don't work, probably I am doing something wrong.
How could I combine these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you got an extra `)` and one missing `)`, try this:

```
elseif( is_category( 'latest-news' ) || ( is_single() && in_category( 'latest-news' ) ) ) {
```

ps: You should also post any PHP error you get.